# Is the Fighter the only one who gets more attacks per round now?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

So, looking at the classes, I see that the Fighter is the only one who lists Extra Attack in his table. I notice the Monk also gets one as a bonus action, and possibly two more by spending a ki point (to a total of three, not four).
What happened to dual weapon fighting? Does the ranger no longer get more attacks?

Comment: There is indeed dual weapon fighting, maybe finish reading the PHB then ask?

Comment: But the dual weapon fighting feat doesn't grant more attacks.
I see that the Ranger does get one more at 5th level, and there's a multiattack feature inside an archetype... Hmm. So not ALL rangers get it, then.

Comment: @Ulrich you need to read the combat chapter, off hand attack is an action granted to all PCs.

Comment: It's really a whole lot easier to understand any sort of system if you read all of the rules before arriving at any conclusions or inferences, or even asking questions.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It should be noted that that answer, the top answer, was recommending not answering the question (and downvoting), not marking off topic.

Comment: @Ulrich [The elements of a good question are found here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  One of the downvotes, mine, was earned from not adhering to that site guideline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most martial classes get extra attacks, though not as many as the fighter (The Rogue is an exception to this, they do not get one).

Rangers get a second attack, as do certain types of Bards, Warlocks and other classes.

A full listing of all the the classes that get extra attacks would be more than is appropriate here, but many classes get it.

Two weapon fighting is available to any PC. When you make an attack with a light melee weapon, you may spend a bonus action to take an attack with a light melee weapon in your other hand, but you don't add your ability score to the damage of this attack.

Comment: Ulrich, comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29454/discussion-on-answer-by-wax-eagle-is-the-fighter-the-only-one-who-gets-more-atta). Or, if you have a new question, ask it in a new question post (re-reading the relevant part of the rules before doing so, of course, so the exact point of the question is clearly written).